# How to step through javascript code that is bound to a button

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to inspect the javascript code that runs when I click on a button in a complicated site that I did not create.

Is there an easy way to do this?

There are many javascript files, so I'm not sure how to work out which code is bound to the button.

-- Edit --

I'm actually working with a SharePoint site. Here's what the button looks like:

```
<a unselectable="on" href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;" class="ms-cui-ctl-large " aria-describedby="Ribbon.Library.Actions.ConnectToClient_ToolTip" mscui:controltype="Button" role="button" id="Ribbon.Library.Actions.ConnectToClient-Large">
    <span unselectable="on" class="ms-cui-ctl-largeIconContainer">
        <span unselectable="on" class=" ms-cui-img-32by32 ms-cui-img-cont-float">
            <img unselectable="on" alt="" src="/_layouts/15/1033/images/formatmap32x32.png?rev=23" style="top: -307px; left: -137px;">
        </span>
    </span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="ms-cui-ctl-largelabel">Connect to<br>Outlook</span>
</a>
```

The anchor tag has an id. How can I search through all the source files for it in the Dev Tools? There are 34 source javascript files. Do I have to manually open each one? ..

Also, I figured this was pretty useless because it's possible to bind code via classes and any other CSS selector. Do I just pray that they used the ID?

I was kinda hoping that the Dev Tools had a way of returning all code bound to the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the DevTools and inspect the button you'll get the tab that lists the styles of this element. Next to this tab is the Event Listeners tab. There are listed all the event listeners for the current element from all the files. You can put a breakpoint in the code that attached the event listener.

Sadly this is a bit more complicated if the site is using jQuery since all the subscriptions are done in the jQuery file but still you'll be able to iterate through it with F10/F11.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't noticed the Event Listeners tab. That should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these simple steps:

1. If you are using Firefox, open `Firebug` > `Script` tab (install Firebug plugin if you dont have it already), if you are using Chrome, open `Developer Tools` > `Sources` tab (Chrome has Developer Tools by default and doesnt need to be installed)
2. Locate the code for the button in HTML
3. Setup a `breakpoint` to the button by clicking on the left side
4. Now reload the page. The page will stop at the breakpoint.
5. Now hit `F10` to go step by step through the code.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm familiar with the Chrome Dev Tools. But I'm stuck on point 2. How can I locate the code for the button?

Comment: @MattFitzmaurice Walk yourself through the HTML from the starting of the <body> and you will find the button.

Comment: :) Thanks. I can find the button easily via 'Inspect Element'. I was having trouble finding the associated code. You can see in the answer above that I needed to use the 'Event Listeners'.

Answer (score 0):

Use the web developer tool that is the easiest way to analyst and debug the JavaScript.
Web developer tools plug-ins ships with lot of browsers itself like Firefox,Google chrome

Comment: Thanks. I'm familiar with the Chrome Dev Tools. How do I locate the code that is linked to the button?

Comment: Find the button id and find the JavaScript functions attached to that button. example if you want the button click event find the click function attached with that button id

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails and you've got some really complex code that you are still trying to learn:

Use the profiler tool.

In Chrome, start your profiler then hit the button, then stop the profiler.  It will give a list of everything that was called. If you are using jQuery, you may have to look over the stack to figure out where jQuery calls your code -- but its not too hard.